# Randomly picking 2 integers to compute a third one with equiprobability

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I have a problem, that might be simple but I just don't see it for the moment.

Supposing you have a finite set of integers $S_1$, I am looking for a simple function that when randomly picking two integers $x$ and $y$ from $S_1$ and returns another integer $z$ in a second defined set $S_2$ (such as $[-16, 16], [-20, 20]\ldots$), knowing that if we repeat the function a large number of times, z has to appear in a **equiprobable** manner.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If $S_1$ is $[0,9]$ (by which I mean the set of integers between $0$ and $9$), and $S_2=[0,99]$, would $z=10x+y$ work?

Comment: You'll get better responses if you say where this problem comes from and what work you have done on it. Or at least what your thoughts are on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cardinality of $S_2$ does not divide
 that of $S_1 \times S_1$, it can't be done.  If it is divisible, it's easy.

Comment: If it's divisible and the simple function can still be random, that is. Otherwise, it's possible only if $|S_2|=|S_1|^2$

Comment: Don't you have this backwards?  After all, if $S_2$ has just a single element, you'll certainly pick it in an equiprobable manner, no matter how large $S_1$ is.

Comment: Oops of course yes, that's what I meant.  I'll edit.  Thanks for catching it.